# Mysql update row to remove int secondary column gaps

Tags: mysql, performance, gaps-in-data

That's how my table looks like with a couple of records.

```
+--ID--+--DESC--+--ORD--+
| 001  |  lal1  |  003  |
| 002  |  lal2  |  001  |
| 003  |  lal3  |  002  |
| 005  |  lal4  |  004  |
| 006  |  lal5  |  006  |
| 007  |  lal8  |  009  |
+------+--------+-------+
```

The `ORD` column is necessary to establish a specific order, which comes from another system that is not the same as that of the PKey.

At this point, the problem is the gaps in the ORD column;
As you can see, there is no number 5,7,8.

This query's not work properly:

```
SET @count = 0;

UPDATE table 
SET table.ord = @count := @count + 1;

ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

because it does not remove gaps.

I would like a result like the following:

```
+--ID--+--DESC--+--ORD--+
| 001  |  lal1  |  003  |
| 002  |  lal2  |  001  |
| 003  |  lal3  |  002  |
| 005  |  lal4  |  004  |
| 006  |  lal5  |  005  |
| 007  |  lal8  |  006  |
+------+--------+-------+
```

Working with UNIX there is the command SORT and taking it to a temporary I can make it possible, but I do not know if there is any command that allows me to do it through a query on the table in real time in MySQL.

Comment: In fact an `UPDATE` statement like the one you show will remove gaps, but you should add `ORDER BY ord` to make sure it preserves the order. Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d29db/1

Comment: sure @BillKarwin i find the same example, thank.

Answer (score 0):

Solve with this:

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE tableSET table.ord = @count:= @count + 1 ORDER BY table.ord ASC;
```

add `Order By`